# How to handle an infinite background task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, lifecycle

I want to develop an app which downloads small files continuously when my app is not in the foreground and sends a notification if certain conditions are met.

Problem is that periodic agents have a scheduled interval of 30 minutes and a duration of 10 seconds, while resource-intensive agents have a duration of 10 minutes and need an external power source.

How could I do to achieve my goal ?

Comment: What units is _"mn"_ as in _"30mn"_?

Comment: Are you saying that your app is forcibly disconnected after 10 seconds?  Can you resume download later?

Comment: Anyway that's what the doc says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx . And I don't download a huge file, I download files of 7 bytes continuously.

Comment: With current WP limitations, your options are all bad or worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind upgrading your Application to WP8.1 then you can use a very simple class to download a file in the background.

[BackgroundDownloader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader). There is really good example at the bottom of the page as well.

Useful Links if you want to understand more:

[Transferring data in the background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh452975%28v=win.10%29)  Describes the events of the BackgroundDownloader.

---

Periodic Tasks should really only do something very simple IMHO (that is why they have those restriction, not download something continuously) for example, Grab the latest news from a feed and update the Secondary Title.

Comment: From what I could see, BackgroundDownloader class is made for huge downloads, there is no way to process the file, nor restarting a download when the previous is finished if my app is not in foreground.